# esp8266 based project using xampp

Tags: xampp, arduino-esp8266

I've tried uploading the below code into NodeMCU for sending data into MySQL using Xampp Webserver. I want to send values from sensors to the MySQL database through ESP8266. This is the code I have tried

```
#include <MySQL_Connection.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

#define sensorPin1 analogRead(A0)
WiFiServer server(301);
const char *ssid =  "internet";    
const char *pass =  "abcdefghi";
const char* host = "x.x.x.x"; 
byte mac[6];
WiFiClient client;
MySQL_Connection conn((Client *)&client);

char INSERT_SQL[] = "INSERT INTO test.tester(id,sensor) VALUES ('', %d)";
char query[128];

IPAddress server_addr(x,x,x,x);          // MySQL server IP
char user[] = "root";           // MySQL user
char password[] = "";       // MySQL password

void setup() {

 Serial.begin(9600);
       delay(10);

       Serial.println("Connecting to ");
       Serial.println(ssid); 

       WiFi.begin(ssid, pass); 
       while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
          {
            delay(500);
                Serial.print(".");
          }
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println("WiFi connected"); 

  WiFi.macAddress(mac);
  Serial.print("MAC: ");
  Serial.print(mac[5],HEX);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(mac[4],HEX);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(mac[3],HEX);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(mac[2],HEX);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(mac[1],HEX);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.println(mac[0],HEX);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Assigned IP: ");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("");

      Serial.println("Connecting to database");

  while (conn.connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password) != true) {
    delay(5);
    Serial.print ( "." );
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Connected to SQL Server!");  

}

void loop() {

  int sensor =  sensorPin1;
  delay(10000); //10 sec

  sprintf(query, INSERT_SQL, sensor);
  Serial.println("Data Recorded.");
  Serial.println(query);

  MySQL_Cursor *cur_mem = new MySQL_Cursor(&conn);

  cur_mem->execute(query);

  delete cur_mem;

}
```

But when I execute this program, the chip is getting connected to WiFi but is is not getting connected to the database.
Any solutions please!?

Comment: Is the MySQL server even accessible outside localhost?

Comment: @gre_gor yes its is accessible, but even if I am accessing it from localhost for starters, I am not able to receive any kind of data in a table